# Extract pdf from database and display it on my cshtml

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

i working on a project, that shall show resturant information along with an pdf file. I have been able to save my pdf to my database. But i don't know how to extrakt it from my database and then display it on my .cshtml.

I'm working with VS and MVC4 with an MSSQL server.

Heres the code to download the file.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(TempVM.Resturang.PDF_File.FileName);
var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
TempVM.Resturang.PDF_File.SaveAs(filePath);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
br.Close();
fs.Close();

TempVM.Resturang.PDF_FileName = fileName;
TempVM.Resturang.PDF_Data = bytes;
TempVM.Resturang.PDF_ContentType = filePath;
```

The file comes from the object

```
public HttpPostedFileBase PDF_File { get; set; }
```

And the data is stored as

```
[PDF_Data]    VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
[PDF_ContentType] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
[PDF_FileName] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
```

With the sql code to store it

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PDF_FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Resturang.PDF_FileName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PDF_ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Resturang.PDF_ContentType;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PDF_Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = Resturang.PDF_Data;
```

But know i dont know how to extrakt my pdf file stored in my database and then display it on my .cshtml page so i can view it and mayby download it from the -cshtml page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need is an action to output your PDF, e.g.:

```
    public ActionResult GetDocument(int id)
    {
        TempVM model = GetViewModel();

        if (model.PDF_Data.Length > 0)
        {
            return File(model.PDF_Data, model.PDF_ContentType);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("NotFound");
        }
    }
```

And then on your output view, you just include this as a hyperlink, like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View doc", "GetDocument", new {ID = 1})
```

Comment: Thx mate! U sloved it for me! Really really thankfull!

Comment: No problem.  If this worked for you, consider clicking the tick at the side - cleans up the question and take it out of the 'open' list.