# How display var-binary data to PDF in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

how to display var-binary data to PDF in MVC. can you share anybody how to display var-binary data as PDF in MVC

here i tried in MVC, but not display PDF.

> MVC Code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewPDF()
    {
        string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
        embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a>";
        embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
        embed += "</object>";
        TempData["Embed"] = string.Format(embed, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Files/1.pdf"));

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

here is calling physical path, but i need to read and display var-binary so can anybody share idea?.,

one more thing i displayed var-binary to PDF in asp.net application but unable to display in MVC.

```
> Asp.net code samples:-
window.open('http://localhost:58158/AspForms/pdf.aspx' + '?id=' + id, '', 'width=800, height=650, top=0, left=250, status=0,toolbar=0');
>
```

> pdf popup page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"800px\" height=\"550px\">";
            embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
            embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
            embed += "</object>";

            ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Id="), Request.QueryString["id"]);
        }
```

FileCS.ashx:-

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FileCS" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
public class FileCS : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        #region
        int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        byte[] bytes = { };
        string fileName = "", allow = "N";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Scan_Pdf_File FROM PWF_InvoiceMain WHERE InvoiceID=@Id and Enabled = 1";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sdr.HasRows == true)
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                        bytes = (byte[])sdr["PDFFile"];
                        fileName = "Report";
                        allow = "A";
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        if (allow == "A")
        {            
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.Charset = "";
            if (context.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
            {
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            }
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.End();            
        }
        else
        {

        }
        #endregion
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but in MVC unable to display var-binary to PDF...

Comment: Is the PDF data retrieved from database or file system? I think you can use return type as `FileStreamResult` or `FileResult` depending your needs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781996/extract-pdf-from-database-and-display-it-on-my-cshtml for an example to consider with.

Comment: it is a var-binary data from DB, so how to bind it that var-binary data to <object> like above i mentioned on Page_Load have <object>  then i push it to Literal, it will call fileCS.ashx file it call --> SELECT Scan_Pdf_File FROM PWF_InvoiceMain WHERE InvoiceID=@Id and Enabled = 1 then convert it into byte to stream, on asp.net application it was worked fine. on MVC only trouble

Answer (score 1):

**popup view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayPDF", "Scan", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">View PDF</a>
    }
```

**on Scan controller:-**

```
public ActionResult DisplayPDF()
        {
            byte[] byteArray = GetPdfFromDB(4);
            MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
            pdfStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            pdfStream.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
        }

        private byte[] GetPdfFromDB(int id)
        {
            #region
            byte[] bytes = { };
            string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Scan_Pdf_File FROM PWF_InvoiceMain WHERE InvoiceID=@Id and Enabled = 1";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (sdr.HasRows == true)
                        {
                            sdr.Read();
                            bytes = (byte[])sdr["Scan_Pdf_File"];
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            return bytes;
            #endregion
        }
```